# Image switched when pressed on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner to JavaScript, and want to apply it to a tic-tac-toe website I'm making. I made the board using HTML tables. I want to make it so that first, the board is clear. Then when you click on a cell once, a picture of an 'x' appears. When a cell is clicked twice, a picture of an 'o' appears.

Here is the HTML and CSS for the table I made.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #003b4d;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>SUPERTAC</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="title">
    <h1>
      Strategic Tic-Tac-Toe
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="lorem-ipsum">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, urna interdum nibh sit volutpat, euismod iaculis arcu eros orci, ut lobortis risus urna, eros scelerisque dolor pellentesque dapibus fames, posuere erat quam mi curabitur.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid">
    <!---turn pictures into buttons--->
    <table class="strategic">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="directions">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

If there is a way to do it using just CSS and HTML that would be even better since I am just learning how to use JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: I added all of my code that I have so far. @AlonEitan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

```
var currentPlayer = 1;

window.onload = function () {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (i = 0; tags.length > i; i++) {
        // add event for every tag
        tags[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

            // chack the cell is empty
            if (isEmpty(this))
                setCharacter(this);
            else
                alert('cell is not empty');

        });
    }

}

function isEmpty(element) {
    if (element.innerText.length > 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

function setCharacter(element) {
    if (currentPlayer == 1) {
        element.innerText = 'X';
        currentPlayer = 2;
    }
    else {
        element.innerText = 'O';
        currentPlayer = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
  
    $(".icon").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      var icon = $(this).find("i");
      
      if(icon.is(":visible")){
        if(icon.hasClass('fa-close')){
           icon.toggleClass('fa-circle-o');
        }
        else{
          icon.toggleClass("fa-close");
        } 
      }else{
        icon.show();
      }
      
    });
  
});
```

```css
.icon{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .6em .7em; 
}
.icon i{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```